# Why comparison of two md5sum files is not working properly?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, md5

I have 2 lists with files with their md5sum checks and the lists have different paths for the same files.

Example of content in first file with check sums (server.list):

```
2c03ff18a643a1437ec0cf051b8b7b9d  /tmp/fastq1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
c430f587aba1aa9f4fdf69aeb4526621  /tmp/fastq1_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz/
6e6bcd84f264233cf7c428c0cfdc0c03  tmp/fastq1_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz
```

Example of content in two file with check sums (downloaded.list):

```
2c03ff18a643a1437ec0cf051b8b7b9d  /home/projects/fastq1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
c430f587aba1aa9f4fdf69aeb4526621  /home/projects/fastq1_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
6e6bcd84f264233cf7c428c0cfdc0c03  /home/projects/fastq1_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz
```

When I run the following line, I got the following lines:

```
awk -F"/" 'FNR==NR{filearray[$1]=$NF; next }!($1 in filearray){printf "%s has a different md5sum\n",$NF}' downloaded.list server.list

fastq1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz has a different md5sum
fastq1_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz has a different md5sum
fastq1_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz has a different md5sum
```

Why I am getting this message since the first column is the same in both files? Can someone enlighten me on this issue?

Edit:

If I remove the path and leave only the file name, it works just fine.

Edit 2:

As pointed out, there is another possibility of file path form, which does not start with `/`. In this case, I cannot use `/` as the field separator.

Comment: I created the two files using your sample data (including the paths), and ran your awk script. I (correctly) get no putput.

Comment: @pmf thanks for the answer! I really wish tô understand why it's showing the output... Do I have a bug? If so, where? Anyway, i think that i can fairly assume that i don't have corrupted Files, right?

Comment: Is the whitespace between the md5 and the file path the same between the two files? Using `-F"/"` makes it treat that as part of `$1`.

Comment: @RamonTCarmo Try the same as I did. Create new files with the data copied from here (not from your actual files), and see what happens. If there's no output, it must be with your actual files.

Comment: whitespace in array keys matters. this seems to be working: `FNR==NR{filearray[gsub(/ /, "", $1)]=$NF; next }!(gsub(/ /,"",$1) in filearray)`

Comment: Thanks for your answers! As you guys noted, it was the whitespace! Just tried the code provided by @LMC and worked just fine! I'm still learning how to fuse awk. Many thanks, you all! Have a nice week :)

Comment: Added an answer in case you want to accept it.

Comment: Can your file paths ever contain space characters? Can your file paths ever NOT contain `/` characters?

Comment: @RamonTCarmo answer fixed after EdMorton comment.

Comment: If your input really looks like the example you posted then removing white space from $1 will do nothing. If it doesn't look like the example you posted then [edit] your question to fix your example so we can see what's really happening.

Comment: @EdMorton the files are generated using md5sum. I do believe that the files would not have a white space, but they had to be delimited by tab. I don't know why it's handling as white space though... It's possible to have the path without "/" if generate the md5 file in the same directory as the other files.

Comment: Whether the fields are blank or tab separated will not change the result of comparing the $1s across the files. If the fields are tab-separated then `gsub(/ /,"".$1)` wont change the line. if the fields are blank-separated then `gsub(/ /,"",$1)` will change the $1s to be the same in both files and so won't affect the outcome.

Comment: If your file paths don't always start with `/` then you cannot use `/` as the field-separator and you should include a case like that in your sample input/output.

Comment: @EdMorton oh! I see that! Added another example to cover this issue!

Comment: Don;t add multiple separate examples as that causes us more work in copy/pasting/testing, please just provide 1 sample input and the associated expected output covering all of your use cases.

Comment: Sorry! First time posting a question here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumptions:

- filename (sans path) and md5sum have to match
- filenames may not be listed in the same order
- filenames may not exist in both files

Sample data:

```
$ head downloaded.list server.list
==> downloaded.list <==
2c03ff18a643a1437ec0cf051b8b7b9d  /home/projects/fastq1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz   # match
YYYYf587aba1aa9f4fdf69aeb4526621  /home/projects/fastq1_L001_R5_911.fastq.gz   # different md5sum
c430f587aba1aa9f4fdf69aeb4526621  /home/projects/fastq1_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz   # match
MNOPf587aba1aa9f4fdf69aeb4526621  /home/projects/fastq1_L001_R8_abc.fastq.gz   # filename does not exist in other file
ABCDf587aba1aa9f4fdf69aeb4526621  /home/projects/fastq1_L001_R9_004.fastq.gz   # different filename but matching md5sum (vs last line of other file)

==> server.list <==
2c03ff18a643a1437ec0cf051b8b7b9d  /tmp/fastq1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz             # match
c430f587aba1aa9f4fdf69aeb4526621  /tmp/fastq1_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz             # match
XXXXf587aba1aa9f4fdf69aeb4526621  /tmp/fastq1_L001_R5_911.fastq.gz             # different md5sum
TUVWff18a643a1437ec0cf051b8b7b9d  /tmp/fastq1_L999_R6_922.fastq.gz             # filename does not exist in other file
ABCDf587aba1aa9f4fdf69aeb4526621  /tmp/fastq1_L001_R7_933.fastq.gz             # different filename but matching md5sum (vs last line of other file)
```

One `awk` idea to address white space issues as well as verifying filename matches:

```
awk '                                    # stick with default field delimiter of white space but ...
{ md5sum=$1
  n=split($2,arr,"/")                    # split 2nd field on "/" delimiter
  fname=arr[n]

  if (FNR==NR)
     filearray[fname]=md5sum
  else {
     if (fname in filearray && filearray[fname] == $1)
        next
     printf "%s has a different md5sum\n",fname
  }
}
' downloaded.list server.list
```

This generates:

```
fastq1_L001_R5_911.fastq.gz has a different md5sum
fastq1_L999_R6_922.fastq.gz has a different md5sum
fastq1_L001_R7_933.fastq.gz has a different md5sum
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, @markp-fuso! Never occurred to me that the whitespace would be an issue! I'm still learning how to properly use awk.

Answer (score 2):

The whitespace on `$1` used as an array key is causing problems. Removing it:

```
awk -F"/" '{gsub(/ /, "", $1)}; FNR==NR{filearray[ $1]=$NF; next }!($1 in filearray){printf "%s has a different md5sum\n",$NF}' list1.txt list2.txt
```

Comment: @EdMorton thanks for pointing that out. Added a fix for that.